# Print contents of array in oneline

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am new to ruby and was trying out with arrays.i want to print the array in single line.
this is the block of code(please ignore any errors)

```
array=[]

puts "Choose an option: ","1.Push, 2.Pop, 3.Display Length"
choice=gets.to_i
while choice!=4
if choice==1
    puts "enter Number of elements to be pushed"
    n=gets.to_i
    n.times do
      puts "Enter element"
    el=gets.to_s
    array.push el
    end
  puts array
elsif choice==2
    puts array.pop

elsif choice==3
    puts array.length

else
  puts "invalid"
end
end
```

when I print my array in `if choice==1`i get all the outputs on different lines,
example

```
hello
i
am
beginner
to
ruby
```

is there anyway to put the output in single line?
i.e `hello i am beginner to ruby`

EDIT: I have even tried using `puts array.join(' ')`, but that too doesnt work.

Comment: `puts array.join(' ')`

Comment: I even tried that but it prints on the new line with SPACE.

Comment: There are newlines in your string; you should be `chomp`ing the input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all,

```
puts array
```

should be

```
puts array.join(' ')
```

By default, `puts` outputs each element on its own line.

Secondly,

```
el=gets.to_s
```

should be

```
el = gets.chomp
```

`gets` returns a string, so there's not much point in converting a string to a string. But the string returned by `gets` will also end with a newline, so you need to `chomp` that newline off.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `puts array` try `p array` if you want the whole array printed to screen.

Answer (score 2):

New to Ruby as well! I just tried:

```
puts "#{array.inspect}"
```

where `array = [2 3 4 5 6 77 88]`. It resulted in:

```
["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "77", "88"]
```

which is a single line printout, if a quick fix is needed. But `array.join(' ')` is much better.